# Is there a way to concatenate two arrays element-wise in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two 1-D Arrays of text in excel and I want to join them to produce another 1-D array such that each element of the new array is the concatenation of the two corresponding elements of the old arrays.

E.g. joining the two arrays {"A","B"} and {"C","D"} would result in the new array {"AC","BD"}.

Is there any way to do this directly in one excel array formula?

I have tried CONCAT and TEXTJOIN but they both just join all the text into one cell.

I did think I might be able to fudge it by making my two arrays and then just copying a bunch of formulae underneath to concatenate the two cells above them. But I would prefer to do it all in one formula if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is pretty simple:

```
={"A","B"}&{"C","D"}
```

Result:

[image]

Wrap it with `TOCOL` if vertical array is needed.

Or

```
=A1:A2&A4:A5
```

[image]

Wrap it with `TOROW` if horizontal array is needed.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you! Very nicely written answer as well.